# PIG parsing string inputs

Tags: parsing, apache-pig

I have two files,

one is titles.csv and has a movie ID and title with this format:

```
999: Title
734: Another_title
```

the other is a list of user IDs who link to the movie

categoryID: user1_id, ....

```
222: 120
227: 414 551
249: 555
```

Of different sizes (minimum is one user per genre category)

The goal is to first **parse the strings so that they are each split into two (for both files), everything before the ':' and everything after.**

I have tried doing this

```
movies = LOAD .... USING PigStorage('\n') AS (line: chararray)
users = LOAD .... USING PigStorage('\n') AS (line: chararray)

-- parse 'users'/outlinks, make a list and count fields
tokenized = FOREACH users GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line, ':')) AS parameter;
filtered = FILTER tokenized BY INDEXOF(parameter, ' ') != -1;
result = FOREACH filtered GENERATE SUBSTRING(parameter, 2, (int)SIZE(parameter)) AS number;
```

But this is where I got stuck/confused. Thoughts?

I'm also supposed to output the top 10 entries who have the most user IDs in the second part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
movies = LOAD 'file1' AS titleLine;
A = FOREACH movies GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(titleLine,'^(.*):\\s+(.*)$')) AS (movieId:chararray,title:chararray);

users = LOAD 'file2' AS userLine;
B = FOREACH users GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(userLine,'^(.*):\\s+(.*)$')) AS (categoryId:chararray,userId:chararray);
```

**Output1:**

```
(999,Title)
(734,Another_title)
```

**Output2:**

```
(222,120)
(227,414 551)
(249,555 )
```